# Search Integer in Data

Tags: regex

i have little trouble with my regex.

> UBS   GROUP   N (UBSG/CH0244767585)
>   8.02.2017
>   Time    Price   Volume
>   11:37:30    15.44   4447
>   11:37:29    15.44   432

[RegExr: Learn, Build & Test](http://regexr.com/)

First i have found the time and price with this:

Price: `\d+\.\d{1,2}` Time: `\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}`

Now i need the Volume and here is the problem.
The Question: Can i do and condition? And how?

`[^\d+\.\d{1,2}]` and `[^\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}]` and `[\d+]` ?

I have test some things without results. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may capture all three values like this: [`(\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(\d+\.\d{1,2})\s+(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ckkFIt/1). What is the tool/programming language?

Comment: You are right on your way, so your question seems a bit weird! just concatenate three parts with `\s+` & you are done. Does Volume have any special range or sth? what is its minimum & maximum by your domain rules?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, im use c#. Your code give all the values. I want only the Volume. Can i use "is not" with capture? I have try and become no results.

Comment: Yeah sry, my english isnt perfect :/ The Volume dont have special range, its every time other range. What you mean with minimum & maximum by your domain rules?

Comment: Is the text a single multiline string?

Comment: see my answer below. as long as it is an integer (which is what the question header saying), this should be fine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its a single line. :)

Comment: So, if the input is like `UBS GROUP N (UBSG/CH0244767585) 8.02.2017 Time Price Volume 11:37:30 15.44 4447  11:37:29 15.44 432`, my first solution is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may write a regex that will match the whole chunks of strings and will *capture* what you need only.

```
 \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+\d+\.\d{1,2}\s+(\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FxnNSS/1), only `(\d+)` is captured and the value will reside in the `Match.Groups[1]`.

**Details**:

- `\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` - 1 or 2 digitis, `:`, 2 digits, `:` and 2 digits
- `\s+` - 1 or more (`+`) whitespace symbols
- `\d+\.\d{1,2}` - 1+ digits, a literal `.` and then 1 or 2 digits
- `\s+` - 1 or more (`+`) whitespace symbols
- `(\d+)` - *[Capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) #1* that matches and stores 1+ digits in a memory buffer.

C#:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+\d+\.\d{1,2}\s+(\d+)")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
        .ToList();
```

Also, to grab one or more digits at the end of a *line*, you may use `(?m)\d+\r?$` and grab match values:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?m)\d+\r?$")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToList();
```

The `(?m)` inline modifier will make `$` match the end of the *line*, not the whole string. Also, if the line endings are CRLF, you must add `\r?` before `$`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i try to understand that. Im rly newby @regex. Maybe i cant use isNot? With isNot i understand it much bether.

Comment: Do not overcomplicate. Regex is meant to match some text meeting some pattern. If you need just a part of a match, *capture* that part with capturing group(s), then access the captures.

Comment: Maybe u can tell me how i do it with the complicate way? With little example? Thank you much for your descriptions!

Comment: Do you want me to explain your own patterns that I used in my solution above? I thought you know what they mean since you yourself posted them in the question.

Comment: ah no. I need to have the correct syntax for the conditions ^^ Thats all what i needed. Now i try little bit and come back later. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I do it when the problem is finished. :)

Comment: it wont work, maybe its multilines... sry. Have teste some of your stuff without results. Any Idea? In RegExr when im press the multiline flag it works with a small regex i do. In c# it wont work.

Comment: What won't work? Could you please share the exact string literal you have for testing? Note I also modified the 2nd solution, added `\r?`, an optional CR.

Comment: \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+\d+\.\d{1,2}\s+(\d+) gives 0 matches back. And for tests i have use this: (\d+\:\d+\:\d+\s+\d+\.\d+\s+)(\d+) if im understand that corretly gives that 2 groups back or? One Group is Time and price and t he other group is the volume. Im add little Sample on Top!

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct, just whitespaces are also included in the first group. I cannot help you more without **the exact input you have**.

Comment: if you have time i can upload my program.cs for you :) Maybe u have site for it?

Comment: Ok second i do some description for you!

Comment: Sorry, I do not have the time to delve in the whole code, please share the **exact input string you need to run the regex against**. I do not even see the URL (I see it as `userInputUrl = "https://w...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/shares/info_market_data_download.csv?id="+isin;`). Note you run regex against the same content 3 times, when you may use my regex with 3 capturing groups and get all the 3 lists filled out during 1 pass.

Comment: Here: http://webdesign-host.ch/WriteText.txt i have write it to file. Yeah with your code i run new one regex for all. Much Bether if it works.

Comment: and the Code i have added on Top for you.

Comment: oh my god, i see the fold now^^ (\d+\:\d+\:\d+)\;+(\d+\.\d+)\;+(\d+) works..^^ in the console i dont see the ; symbol... ^^ im so sry for wasting your time. Thanks you alot for the bether way with this groups!

Comment: :) https://regex101.com/r/X8K7JJ/1. `Regex.Matches(s, @"(\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2});(\d+\.\d{1,2});(\d+)")`.

Comment: yeah i have see it ^^ so sry, i have accepted your answer for the bether way! :) have nice day and thanks alot !

Comment: Have a good day, too. Note you get 2 rep points for accepting an answer.

Comment: Ah dude little Question, i see u dont escape the ; is this not require? I have with escape and works to. Ty :)

Comment: There is no point escaping a char that has no specific meaning to the regex engine. Only those chars must be escaped that have a special meaning, act as operators (quantifiers, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the volume, without the rest, use `\d+$`.
If not, take the regex suggested by Wiktor in the comments.

Comment: I have tested this and dont work, thanks anyway for your time!

Comment: I can't check it on C#, but it works for me in other languages. the \d+ is an integer of any length (if you want it, you need to have it in parentheses, `(\d+)` and the `$` means "at end of line". could be you have whitespaces after the number?

Comment: `$` means the end of string in .NET regex, only in Ruby it always matches the end of a line.